# How to install Python 3.4.7 on a Toshiba chromebook 2

Tags: python, chromebook

I'd like to code with Python version 3.4.4 or later, preferably 3.4.7 on my Toshiba Chromebook 2. Not entirely sure where to start. Help would be appreciated. Have researched and found that I need to first download a linux system via Crouton to enable me to do this but...english please? New to this

Comment: This is way too broad and thus off-topic for StackOverflow. There are several easy to follow guides to using Crouton on a Chromebook. In English.

Comment: Note, another option, if you don't need a full-fledged Ubuntu chroot, is to simply use [`chromebrew`](https://github.com/skycocker/chromebrew), which is a package manager for chromebooks. Once you install that, you can simply use `crew install python3`